# String Array Parsing (C# & SQL Server)

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server, string, list

I am trying to pass the string array to the DB layer, it first comes as `List<string>` type, then it is converted to a string array.

However, since the string array elements have comma (`,`), SQL Server gets it differently.

Here are the list elements:

```
className":"Ellipse","data":{"x":10,"y":31,"width":195,"height":96,"strokeWidth":5,"strokeColor":"#000","fillColor":"rgba(224,224,224,0.28)"},"id":"fc9746f9-e07b-9847-1824-5cf4468532f7"}
"className\":\"Ellipse\",\"data\":{\"x\":741,\"y\":153,\"width\":-126,\"height\":40,\"strokeWidth\":5,\"strokeColor\":\"#000\",\"fillColor\":\"rgba(224,224,224,0.28)\"},\"id\":\"73bcdc9f-9f57-f162-8264-f5e894fcf6ab\"}],\"backgroundShapes\":"
```

Here is the code that I use to convert list to string

```
string StringLocationDataList = String.Join(" ", LocationDataList.ToArray());
```

I parse this string in DB

Here is the result:

[image]

What I am trying to do is: parse list element into the string array, then send them to the database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you are doing is fine. But in your List<string> `data` has child elements. you have read the child based on data and then insert. Depends on your data requirement to insert into DB.

Comment: How can I read the child basen on data ? When I pass the data, It will always consist of commas.

Comment: Can you post the complete `StringLocationDataList ` output that you get after converting to ToArray();? In case you in general from the output of StringLocationDataList  you will be able to use index to get specific data.

Comment: String array? It looks like JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer;

> DataTable asd = new DataTable();
>                   asd.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
>                   asd.Columns.Add("LocationName", typeof(string));
>
> ```
>             for (int i = 0; i < LocationDataList.Count; i++)
>             {
>                 //asd.Columns.Add(LocationDataList[i], typeof(string));
>                 try { 
>                 asd.Rows.Add(i, LocationDataList[i].ToString());
>                 } catch(Exception ex)
>                 {
>
>                 }
>             }
>             command.Parameters.Add("@PLocationDataList", SqlDbType.Structured, -1).Value = asd;
> ```

Also, User-Defined Table Type is require to meet the DataTable.

Details; [C# DataTable into SQL Server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585285/c-sharp-datatable-into-sql-server-stored-procedure)